# arduino uno behaves differently than duemilanove?

Tags: arduino, serial-port, arduino-uno

I've got a project that runs great on my Duemilanove - I can compile it for 'production' where it runs with no Serial comms, and it does some tweeting. I can compile it for simple Serial messaging and debugging, or I can compile it for verbose Serial activity. All are working fine.  For the Verbose mode, I make use of the Serial.print(F("Some message String"))  to keep strings out of SRAM. Before I started that, I easily ran out of SRAM and of course simple serial mode was fine, but verbose would fail to run, or run erratically.

Now I've picked up an Uno R3 and loaded my software onto it.  I loads fine, but will not communicate on serial at all in verbose mode (and other operations seem to have failed too) but in simple serial mode, it works fine, and compiled for "production" it works fine.

The Specs say that the Uno has the same memory configuration as the Duemilanove.  Is there some SRAM difference?   Does the Serial.print(F()) not work the same in the Uno?   This is an OSEPP Uno R3 - any experience with probs there?  I know earlier ones were flashed wrong, and needed to be pgm'd w/ an alternative target spec'd, but this seems fine.  (Using Mac OSX 10.8.4, and have updated FTDI 2.2.18)

Thx for any suggestions.
-Ross.

Comment: which IDE are you using?

Comment: change the baud rate of the serial.print. May be a timing thing

Comment: does the verbose work with out the F()

Comment: Using the Arduino 1.0.5 enviro. Changed baud rate from 19.2 down to 9.6 w/o any change.  The verbose without F()'s doesn't work on either board, cuz the strings load up the SRAM.

Comment: Later - issues seem to be related to interrupts. Debug continuing.  Code's too large to post, but if I narrow it down I'll post relevant fragments or my sol'n.